# Get data/body from jso that was posted via javascript

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have the following:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "does/work")]
        public bool DoesWork() {
            bool Success = false;

            IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;


            return Success;
        }
```

I can post successfully via POSTMAN but I'm unable to get the json I placed inside the body as raw text, how can I get the data in c# as a string?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Though you send the parameter value in the body of the Post request, you need to accept value of the parameter through method parameter. Just add parameter to you method and it should resolve your issue.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "does/work")]
    public bool DoesWork(WorkDetails workDetails) {
        bool Success = false;
        var work = worDetails.something; //if the type matches with your json content, you should have the values populated under work details
        IncomingWebRequestContext woc = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest;


        return Success;
    }
```

Comment: So i have to make a class that contains the values of the json? so List<WorkDetails> ?

Comment: It could be any object, (WorkDetails is just an example), but you should accept the object exactly same as what you used to serialize to json